# Random category with recent post title and thumbnail

Tags: categories, post-thumbnails

This code below works perfect to pull the title of five random categories, the issue is for each random category I want the latest post title and thumbnail but where and how do I add the post query?

```
<?php
//display random sorted list of terms in a given taxonomy
$counter = 0;
$max = 5; //number of categories to display
$taxonomy = 'category';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
shuffle ($terms);
//echo 'shuffled';
if ($terms) {
foreach($terms as $term) {
    $counter++;
    if ($counter <= $max) {
    echo '<p><a href="' . get_category_link( $term->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a></p> ';
    }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong a [`the_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post) function will take the post info into the loop. If so, then the [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) and [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) will do the rest for you.

```
<?php
//display random sorted list of terms in a given taxonomy
$counter = 0;
$max = 5; //number of categories to display
$taxonomy = 'category';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
shuffle ($terms);

the_post();
if ($terms) {
foreach($terms as $term)
    {
        $counter++;
        if ($counter <= $max)
        {
            echo '<p><a href="' . get_category_link( $term->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a></p> ';
            echo '<p><a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' . the_title() . '</a></p>';
            echo '<p><a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' . the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ) . '</a></p>';
        } //endif ($counter <= $max)
    }
} //endif ($terms)
?>
```

> <sup>**NOTE:** I haven't tested it. Please let me know whether it works or not.</sup>

Comment: Almost there, the output is the url not the thumbnail or title thanks for helpnig really need this.

Comment: ok the url is the permalink

Comment: the title only works but not the thumbnail, the permalink is not linking it writes out.

Comment: If your images are from post_thumbnail (commonly known as: Featured Image) then it'll be viewed. If it's not, then won't.

Comment: Is there a way to get? the_post_thumbnail() is not working

Comment: Enable Featured Image into your theme by putting `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` into your theme's `functions.php` ([see more options here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)). Then add Featured Image with your post, it will work inshALLAH. ...If you want to view the first image of the post body (not a featured image) then that will be a different issue.